# Extract host + one folder from path

Tags: regex, perl, hive

Could you help me figure out a regular expression that would extract from url:

1. host name when there is no folder specified in the path that follows it
   e.g.

   ```
   http://jj.com/' -> 'jj.com
   http://jj.com/index.php' -> 'jj.com
   http://jj.com/query?q=http://kk.uk' -> 'jj.com
   ```
2. host name + one folder from path when there is at least one folder specified in the path
   e.g.

   ```
   'http://jj.com/site/index.php' -> 'jj.com/site'
   'http://jj.com/site/second/aldldls.html' -> 'jj.com/site'
   ```

Is it possible to do that with just one regular expression?

BTW I will be using regex_extract function from hive but any variation of regex (e.g. perl regex) that can do that would be extremely useful.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? There should be modules on CPAN that can handle this. [URI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI) perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

for (<DATA>) {
    s!^http://([^/]+/([^\?/]+/)?).*!$1!;
    s!/\s*$!!;
    print "$_\n";
}

__DATA__
http://jj.com/
http://jj.com/index.php
http://jj.com/query?q=http://kk.uk
http://jj.com/site/index.php
http://jj.com/site/second/aldldls.html
```

Output:

```
jj.com
jj.com
jj.com
jj.com/site
jj.com/site
```

Answer (score 2):

```
use 5.010;
use URI;

for (
    'http://jj.com/',
    'http://jj.com/index.php',
    'http://jj.com/query?q=http://kk.uk',
    'http://jj.com/site/index.php',
    'http://jj.com/site/second/aldldls.html',
) {
    my $u = URI->new($_);
    say (
        ($u->path_segments)[2]
            ? join q(/), $u->host, ($u->path_segments)[1]
            : $u->host
    );
}
```

Output

```
jj.com
jj.com
jj.com
jj.com/site
jj.com/site
```